# Why do the django-voting template tags not work?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-voting

I've installed the Django-voting app [found here](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/), but I am unable to get the template tags to work. For example, from what I've read, simply running

```
{% load voting_tags %}
{% score_for_object object_name as score %}
```

should work, but it errors with a simple `Invalid block tag: 'score_for_object'`.

I have downloaded the app and run setup.py and verified that it installed by casting a vote in the Django Python shell. I have also added 'voting' to the list of installed apps, and moved the 'voting' folder to my project. I have also tried adding `"voting.templatetags.voting_tags",` to my list of template context processors in settings.py.

Am I missing something? [According to the readme](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/source/browse/trunk/docs/overview.txt#9), there is no more setup after simply ensuring that the module is present on Python path (which I believe installing it with setup.py provides), adding it to installed_apps, and running `syncdb`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have tried to use the command `{% load voting_tags %}` in my template. Note that the location of the tags in the voting module is `voting/templatetags/voting_tags.py`. The application now gives me an error:

```
'voting_tags.py' is not a valid tag library: Template library voting_tags.py not 
found, tried django.templatetags.voting_tags.py, 
   django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.voting_tags.py,voting.templatetags.voting_tags.py,
django.contrib.admin.templatetags.voting_tags.py
```

Notice that it is actually trying the correct directory, being voting.templatetags.voting_tags.py, but it is apparently not being registered as valid. It does contain the required code as specific in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters), namely:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
```

Nevertheless, I am having no luck. Why might a library of tags not be considered a valid tag library? It seems to me that it either lacks the correct code to make it a tag library (which, as shown above, it does possess), or there is some sort of path issue where `voting.templatetags.voting_tags.py` is somehow not finding a file at all. Any insight would help me out quite a bit.

Thanks,

ParagonRG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template tags are different from template context processors. Have you [loaded the template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#load)?

```
{% load voting_tags %}
```

Note that `{% load voting_tags.py %}` is incorrect also.

Comment: I have indeed tried that (as you were answering this question). Please see my edit above.

Comment: @Paragon The exception seems weird: `"'voting_tags.py' is not a valid tag library"` and `.py` in following lines. the `.py` is abnormal there. Can you clean up all previous modifications of voting, for example those in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, only keep `'voting'` inside `INSTALLED_APPS` and try again?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out! I've been looking around, and it looks like I botched the `{% load %}` command in my tiredness. I was using `{% load voting_tags.py %}`. If you can, for the sake of future readers, please edit the answer to indicate that this error is caused when somebody uses the `load` command accordingly.